# Android Canot call method of external class from doInBackground async task

Tags: java, android, email, android-asynctask

i want to call from external method in doInBackground from another class for async email sending. But always get this exception message:

```
01-26 19:01:20.281: E/SMARTT(7131): doInBackground method cannot be processed
01-26 19:01:20.281: E/SMARTT(7131): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()



 protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE,"DOING IN BACKGROUND");
                String typeOfEmail = (String) params[0];
                Map<String, String> data = (Map<String, String>) params[1];
                Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE,data.get("ean"));


                AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
                helper.sendLogsByEmail(typeOfEmail, data);
                return "test";
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE,"doInBackground method cannot be processed", e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
        }
```

How to call method from another class in doInBackGround (if is it possible)?

Comment: Can you post the code of your sendLogsByEmail method ? The exception is likely caused by something in that method, hard to say without the complete stacktrace ...

Comment: Code is quite long, so i cannot paste here, but i'm using in method this:

// Solve problem with sending of the email on backgroud of the App
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Maybe it causing problems? I used it if i send email non-sync.